# Screen resolution repositioning (broken screen)

Tags: nvidia, lubuntu, display, display-resolution, xrandr

I have a laptop with the top 47 pixels in height broken. The original screen resolution is 1360x768 so the new resolution has to be 1360x721. I'd like to know if i can reposition the resolution to the bottom part of the screen.

Things i tried:

I made a new custom resolution of 1360x674 but with this resolution i lose 47 pixels in height both on top and bottom.

Comment: No, not possible.

Comment: Are you sure? https://askubuntu.com/questions/261363/screen-resolution-repositioning-broken-laptop-screen. The script seems to work for him but not for me.

Comment: That script was for Unity. Are you running Unity? Which Ubuntu release?

Comment: I'm running on Lubuntu 19.04

Comment: So, LXQt, not Unity. And the problem is different, the other is with a corner. A new, smaller resolution may avoid that because the new smaller area is 'centered'. But it's not possible to use xrandr to create a new smaller resolution and have the new smaller area moved down. You'll always loose lines top and bottom.